# Resolve multiple IPv4 addresses by a hostname

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns, ipv4

I have different hosts in a network and want their IP addresses. (They are known by their hostname address, i.e. foo.local) I found several tools und programs which find one IPv4 address, which is "the first one found" and this can also be a link locale address, which doesn't fit to my implementation. Since I need this for a program, a library or a program with parseable output would be necessary.

Why am I not using the default DNS module? It doesn't seem to work with .local hostnames and the network doesn't necessarily have a DNS server / router.

OS is Ubuntu, platform is node.js.

Multicast DNS might be the answer here, but haven't found a reliable module or other implementation yet. All my devices with hostname to resolve are supporting multicast DNS.

Comment: are you trying to get multiple hosts with the same name to get back multiple ips or to query at once a list of host names and get back a list of ips ?

Comment: I have a method, which first gets a list of host names. foo.local, bar.local, foobar.local. After that I try to resolve each of these hostnames. First foo.local could have 169.254.233.20 and 196.168.1.50 and 10.220.50.199. I want all of these addresses. (Or at least both addresses which aren't link locale) The other hostnames could have the same amount of addresses to resolve.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback says it returns a list of addresses. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well with local host names. (I'm unable to resolve any *.local hostname, which is my requirement) The other issue is: The network where the application is running doesn't necessarily have a router or another potential DNS server. (That's why I expect multicast DNS to be the answer to this)